# Power BI How to remove duplicate rows?

Tags: powerbi, duplicates, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

In my report view, I have a table where the rows are repeated twice => once for each position available. I want to show only one row for each employee with his latest position. How can I accomplish this?

| Name | Project | Date | Position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | PowerProject | 01-01-2021 | Engineer |
| John Smith | PowerProject | 01-01-2021 | Senior Engineer |

Comment: How do you isolate this «latest» position?

Comment: position comes from another table where there is a column that indicated the actual date of the latest position

Comment: And how are these tables related? You are giving way too little information in your question to provide any reasonable answer, given your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Sort on the date. Group on the name. Choose **All Rows** as the function and change the code from _ to Table.Last(_) then expand

Comment: This will not work on the sample data, the rows are identical except for `Position`.

Comment: Then what makes a position the last position. You can still group as is and take last row if already sorted

Comment: That is my question to OP. There is ostensibly a different table with dates to be used. I think any approach that relies on an assumption of correct row ordering is risky and prone to error.

Comment: Ah. Yes. Agreed